# DocuSign GET completed document in binary base64 format?

Tags: base64, docusignapi

Is it possible to GET the completed document in binary base64 format with the REST API? 
I can retrieve the completed document in as a PDF, but I need it in base64 format. This is for our automated process.

This is the Request URL
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxx/envelopes/xxxx/documents/1/

DocuSign support suggested that I post the question here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your documents are not very big, you can use [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf) which is like a WEBhook, to get the document in base64 format. Also via API, pass header as Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 to get document in base64 format